# Remove "attachment/" from the URL of attachment pages

Tags: permalinks, attachments

Currently, the media for a page on `/hello-world/` is shown on `/hello-world/attachment/image-name/`. Is it possible to remove `attachment` from this URL, and make it `/hello-world/image-name/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't include %category% anywhere in your custom permalink string, then it won't need the 
"attachment" text. Also, don't use numeric slugs for the page/post name. Same basic problem occurs there.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code to your functions.php file as provided by [TheDeadMedic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/247223/thedeadmedic):

```
function __filter_rewrite_rules( $rules )
{
    $_rules = array();
    foreach ( $rules as $rule => $rewrite )
        $_rules[ str_replace( 'attachment/', 'media/', $rule  ) ] = $rewrite;
    return $_rules;
}
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', '__filter_rewrite_rules' );

function __filter_attachment_link( $link )
{
    return preg_replace( '#attachment/(.+)$#', 'media/$1', $link );
}
add_filter( 'attachment_link', '__filter_attachment_link' );
```

**SOURCE:**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532508/how-to-change-the-attachment-url-in-wordpress